# onsen css component styles differences when view in chrome app mode

Tags: onsen-ui

I think there is a need for more documentation regarding the css styles.

When the app is ran on the desktop chrome browser, list and list items have borders.
However in the css, I can see this:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi)
  .list__item:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: none;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 1px;
  background-size: 100% 1px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #ddd, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #ddd, #ddd 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

So why are there no borders when we view the app under retina resolution?

Also, with the navigation bar, how does it decide to pick up which css definition?
for example, this only gets applied on some device profiles:

```
.page__status-bar-fill + .page__content {
   padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Is what you want to say in this post the necessity of the documentation of the css of Onsen UI? I'm not sure about what you want to do exactly.